# Java-11 spring-boot deployment to google cloud error: app does not satisfy requirements for [java11]

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, google-cloud-platform, java-11

I am working on a group project where we want to deploy a backend to Google Cloud. The backend is created with Java11, Gradle, and Spring-Boot, and deployed through GitHub with Travis to Google Cloud.

The backend runs as it should at localhost with `./gradlew bootrun`, but when trying to deploy it to Google Cloud we get the following error:

`ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Your application does not satisfy all of the requirements for a runtime of type [java11].  Please correct the errors and try again.`

[image: Java11 error from the terminal]

We recreated this error with the following procedure, removing GitHub and Travis from the equation:

Created a new Spring-Boot project at https://start.spring.io/ with these settings:

- Project: Gradle Project
- Language: Java
- Spring Boot: 2.1.9
- Project Metadata: Options: Java: 11
- Dependencies: Spring Security, Spring Web, GCP Support

Once created, we added the files `app.yaml` and `client_secret.json`.

The `client_secret.json` file contains information about a test-client at gcloud with a lot of permissions.

app.yaml:

```
runtime: java11
env: flex

service: default

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
```

Both `app.yaml` and `client_secret.json` are stored at the same place `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` are.

Then, from the terminal (we used the one in VScode), we ran `gcloud app deploy`. This command first asks us if we want to deploy the backend to a specified google cloud project, listing that it found the `app.yaml` file, the source, and the target. Then, when we pressed Y to continue, the error appears.

Here is the `build.gradle` file, which might be useful(?):

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.9.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Greenwich.SR3")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

So our question is; what does the error mean? And how do we fix it? We have tried a lot of things like editing both `app.yaml` and `build.gradle`, but nothing seems to work. We also struggle to understand where the error occurs, because the backend runs fine at localhost.

We appreciate every response!

Best regards HaavardG :D

Comment: Looking at the [blog entry](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/turn-it-up-to-eleven-java-11-runtime-comes-to-app-engine) for `java11` on gcloud, it mentions something about an `entrypoint` which I don't see in the `app.yaml` file you posted. Did you have this variable defined?

Comment: I think you need to add extra dependencies skip spotbugs dependency, Refer: https://gist.github.com/dineshbhagat/97eff450e9edbd7d006deb35f28e3fd4#add-missing-java-dependencies-in-jdk11

Comment: I believe that the `entrypoint` you're talking about is a JSON-file that I've named `client_secret` that contains information about a service-user in gcloud.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like removing `env: flex` from `app.yaml` did the trick as `env: flex` is somehow not supported by Java11.

I believe...

Answer (score 3):

App Engine Standard and Flexible (both) support Java 11. [The difference between App Engine Standard and Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments) is that Standard has specific versions of Java and Flexible supports any version of Java.

The error given above is due to that you're putting in app.yaml, runtime:java11.
It has to be like following:

app.yaml

```
runtime: custom
env: flex

service: default

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: this field is required, but ignored
```

You have to create Custom Runtimes before in order to deploy it correctly.
[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart) you can see Official documentation to create Custom Runtimes in App Engine Flexible Environment.